# Stop Countdown Timer when user press back button

Tags: android, countdowntimer

My countdowntimer won't stop even though the game is exited by the user. How can I stop it whenever the user presses the back button?

Answer (score 3):

Override onBackPressed in the running activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    someCountDownTimer.cancel();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: In the activity that is running at the moment the back button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Call `youTimer.cancel()` method in `onDestroy`

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not the best place for these types of things. There is no guarantee it will be called when you think it will be. `onPause()` or `onBackPressed()` is much safer

Comment: you are wrong. there is no guarantee that the call `onPause` or `onBackPressed()`

Comment: huh? Both will be called if the user presses the back button

Comment: ok, whether caused by onBackPressed if there is an exception?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying but `onPause()` would cover any time that Activity leaves the foreground. The docs even say that it is not safe to use `onDestroy()` for such things

Comment: I would like to look this document )

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy() not this specific case, obviously, but it is pretty clear that using `onPause()` is safer

Comment: after super.onDestroy or before?

Comment: @codeMagic any suggestion sir/ma'am? :)

Comment: @LabLey Yes, follow the link above that I closed it as and that should work for you.

Comment: Pay attention to this **This method is usually implemented to free resources** this is just what we want to do. you propose to destroy the object although it can still be used